# VBScript sendKeys to already open IE Window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, sendkeys

I am new to VBScript and have an issue regarding sendKeys with already opened IE Window.

Initially I had a script, which opened a new instance of Internet Explorer, wrote some text in a textfield and clicked a button:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "ie_")

Wait IE, 2000
IE.Visible = True
shell.AppActivate IE

Wait IE, 2000
IE.Navigate "http://someurl"

Wait IE, 2000
IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Click
shell.SendKeys "TEST"
Wait IE, 2000
IE.document.getElementById("myButton").Click
...
IE.Quit

End Function

Sub Wait(IE, ms)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep ms
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

This worked perfectly fine.
However now I need to do the same with an already opened instance of IE and this is what I did:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")

Dim objInstances, objIE, IE
Set objInstances = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows
If objInstances.Count > 0 Then '/// make sure we have instances open.
    For Each objIE In objInstances
        If InStr(objIE.LocationURL,"http://someurl") > 0 then
        Set IE = objIE
        End if
Next
End If
shell.AppActivate ("Internet Explorer")

Wait IE, 2000
IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Click
shell.SendKeys "TEST"
Wait IE, 2000
IE.document.getElementById("myButton").Click
...
IE.Quit

End Function

Sub Wait(IE, ms)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep ms
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

This time the the text wouldn't be written into the textfield. 
Has anyone a solution for this?

Comment: I found a solution, that worked for me:
Instead of clicking in the textfield via IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Click, I set the focus to the textfield with IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").focus.

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, that worked for me: Instead of clicking in the textfield via IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Click, I set the focus to the textfield with IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Value` if you want to set value of textfield.

Change these two lines:

```
IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Click
shell.SendKeys "TEST"
```

into:

```
IE.document.getElementById("myTextField").Value = "TEST"
```

Comment: Yes, that would usually work. However in my case the textfield is listening to keyup events to store the input in some variable for processing, so I needed to actually "type" into the textfield.

Comment: Have you added breakpoints to debug the code? Is there any error when you debug the code? If possible I think it could be better if you provide the link or the html codes of the web elements you automate with.

Comment: Unfortunately, since it is work related, I am not allowed to show the actual code, either of the HTML nor of the VBScript.